# How to use PowerShell to open visual studio solution in current directory

Tags: powershell

In my profile settings for powershell I have the following lines:

```
set-alias vs startVisualStudio

function startVisualStudio {
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" .\\*.sln
}
```

When I navigate to a directory containing a `.sln` file and type `vs`, Visual Studio opens to the default start screen telling me that `.\*.sln could not be found`. I have tried several ways of including the asterisk, like `'backtick'*.sln`, `/*.sln` among other, but always the same message. If I replace the `.\*.sln` with a simple `.` and run `vs`, it does open the current directory in visual studio, however not as a solution. How can I write this function to open the .sln in the current directory in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` isn't unwrapped by powershell, it will just pass it on to Visual Studio. Visual Studio won't do it either, so you have to do it yourself. Find all solution files in the folder and get the first one. This will fail if no .sln-files are present.

```
set-alias vs startVisualStudio

function startVisualStudio 
{
    $slnfile = (Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.sln)[0].Name
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" $slnfile
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working recursively (Powershell 7.0) in sub directories too by doing the following:

Open powershell, type

```
echo $profile
```

Open up the location of your profile, save the below into it:

```
function vs
{
Get-ChildItem *.sln -Recurse | Invoke-Item
}
```

Then just type vs into a folder and it will open solution file in any containing folders